# Understanding what "to try" means here

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, infinitives

> What might be done with these? Boxes can usually serve as new storage containers, and almost always serve as very imaginative forts for the kids, not to mention makeshift pet houses during colder weather. And clothing? Imagine taking old clothing and turning them into vests, hats, hanging organizers, or rag rugs. **The only limit to using these items in other ways is one's individual creativity and daringness *to try*.**

I am wondering how the italic part is related to the previous sentence or part. Try what?
***UPDATED***:

My specific problem is the following, as you know both of them could be correct, but I am wondering which one and why ***semantically***, not grammatically:

try using...

try to use

Comment: I'm having difficulty seeing what is still unclear, especially given two good answers. You used the word 'tried' correctly in a comment below, so I conclude you understand what the word 'try' means. The writer elided *what* one is going to try, because it is from earlier in the sentence. Without elision: "The only limit to using these items in other ways is one's individual creativity and daringness to try using these items in other ways". Is there still something unclear about that?

Answer (score 2):

"Try" there is similar to the sense of *try* that underlies "trial and error".

Personal creativity (or the lack thereof) is the only limit on using household items for purposes for which they were not intended--that, and lacking the daring one needs to try [new things] and possibly fail.

Comment: I cannot get what you tried to tell me.

Comment: *Try*, used intransitively without a complement, can have the meaning "to do something in order to see if it will produce a desired effect or outcome".

Comment: To "make an attempt" is the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Your question:

> Try what?

"What" is implied by the contents of the preceding clause, in particular:

> using these items in other ways

In English the object of a verb and sometimes the subject of a sentence can be implied, or not repeated, if the writer feels like the object or subject has been explained by the context.

In this case, the writer simply stopped the sentence after **to try** rather than repeating what he had just stated.